# Chamar ion-view em função

Tags: angularjs, framework, ionic

Estou iniciando em Ionic e AngularJS, já googlei bastante e não achei nada a respeito desta simples duvida.

consigo navegar de boa entre as *ion-view* "Page1" e "Page2" utilizando os botões:

```html
<ion-view view-title="Page1">
  <ion-content>
    <h1>Page 1</h1>
    <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/app/page2">Page 2</a>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>

<ion-view view-title="Page2">
  <ion-content>
    <h1>Page 2</h1>
    <a class="button icon icon-right ion-chevron-right" href="#/app/page1">Page 1</a>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Porem gostaria de executar isso através de uma função:

```js
function EventoTal(){

      carregue("page2");

}
```

Sem a necessidade de clicar no botão.

Em jQuery `$(elemento).show();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não se irá funcionar com Ionic, mas como ele é baseado em Web, podemos tentar o seguindo que é o código equivalente ao que o `<a href="#/app/page2">Page 2</a>` faz:

```
location.hash = "/app/page2";
```

Ou assim para manter o histórico da pilha de paginas:

```
if(history.pushState) {
    history.pushState(null, null, '#/app/page2');
}
else {
    location.hash = '#/app/page2';
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! isso mesmo! Tinha tentado parecido, porém sem sucesso.

Comment: @PatrickLobo, serio que deu certo? Hehe. Fico feliz de ter ajudado, e eu nunca tive contato com Ionic, apesar de já ter lido algumas coisas sobre, então a resposta foi baseada em meu conhecimento Web. Hehe.